# How can I incorporate Google Analytics results into my Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics

I have a Rails 3 app where each customer has his own subdomain. I am using Google Analytics to track the traffic, and I'm using their subdomain options.

Now I would like to display these results in the admin section of my application under each subdomain. Is there an API that I can access to display this information to my users so that they can track traffic to their specific sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the GARB library http://www.viget.com/extend/google-analytics-api-with-ruby-and-garb-making-it-even-easier/

Code from their site:

```
profile = Garb::Profile.first('UA-XXXXXX-XX')

class Pageviews
  extend Garb::Resource
  metrics :pageviews
end

# Now get those pageviews!

profile.pageviews
```

Comment: Getting this results… [code]<Garb::ResultSet:0x105f72690 @sampled=false, @total_results=1, @results=[#<OpenStruct pageviews="181760">]>[/code], just no clue on how to parse the results; is there a specific way to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics and Rails in 5 EASY Steps:

If you are in Rails 3, I just found a great solution for doing Google Analytics in Rails apps.

(1) In your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rack-google_analytics', :require => "rack/google_analytics"
end
```

(2) Bundle Install

(3) In your config/application.rb (put this in the class definition section - careful not to drop it in a module.  I put mine right under "class Application"):

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  config.middleware.use("Rack::GoogleAnalytics", :web_property_id => "UA-0000000-1")
end
```

(4) Initiate your Google Analytics account

(5) Copy and paste that funky web_property_id from Google's supplied code into the code from (3), replacing 'UA-000000-1'

That's it!

I originally found this solution here:
[David Bock Article](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/david_bock/2010/12/google_analytics_and_rails3)

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote for this.  Aren't users supposed to comment when they downvote?

Comment: I don't believe it's what he was looking for. I think he meant how to show the results to his users.

Comment: I googled for the question that you have provided the answer for. I agree that it is not an answer to the question. I suggest you update your answer with a header like "If you want to **track** visits with Google Analytics", because this seems to be what you have provided an excellent answer for. Don't delete it.

Comment: I also suggest that you provide a link to the question that you actually answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540887/question-about-google-analytics-tracking-w-rails